# Google Apps Script : The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent

Tags: google-apps-script, url, xpath, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write a script for google apps script that will create an event everyday at 09:00 (UTC-4) and reporting the value displayed in the xpath //div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a displayed in this URL https://etherscan.io/address/0x260ee8f2b0c167e0cd6119b2df923fd061dc1093

I tried to change so many things but i still don't understand why i get this error message :

"Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent." Line 21

Please help

```
function createEvent() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(9);
  startTime.setMinutes(0);
  startTime.setSeconds(0);
  startTime.setUTCHours(-4);
  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(10);
  endTime.setMinutes(0);
  endTime.setSeconds(0);
  endTime.setUTCHours(-4);
  var event = {
    summary: 'Etherscan Value Report',
    start: {
      dateTime: startTime.toISOString(),
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endTime.toISOString(),
    }
  };
  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(event);
}

function reportSpanValue() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://etherscan.io/address/0x260ee8f2b0c167e0cd6119b2df923fd061dc1093");
  var html = response.getContentText();
  var xpath = '//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/a';
  var value = xpath.evaluate(html, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;
  Logger.log(value);
}

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('reportSpanValue')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(9)
    .everyDays(1)
    .atMinute(0)
    .create();
}
```

To resolve this issue I tried to pass an event object to the createEvent method, not a string. But it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps you should look at this example [createEventSeries()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEventSeries(String,Date,Date,EventRecurrence))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Etherscan Value Report',startTime,endTime)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked but now I don't get the xpath value in my event description but only "Etherscan Value Report" and I don't know how to get my value here. I will try another way with the XPathXMLParsing Apps Script library

Comment: I don't understand your problem, startTime and endTime are variables in your script and the other parameter is just a string.

Comment: "Etherscan Value Report" should be a variable also, i did a mistake